# error in parsing xml in drupal

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I used to parse some RSS XML files with a PHP script beginning that way

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pinterest.com/myaccount/rss');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contenu = curl_exec($curl);
$xml = new simpleXMLElement ($contenu);
```

but for some days now I got that error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'
>
> `[Tue Mar 03 15:23:33.141113 2015] [:error] [pid 4748] [client 172.19.8.44:56794] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /var/www/html/drupal/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code:6\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/drupal/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code(6): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')\n#1 /var/www/html/drupal/includes/common.inc(1743): eval()\n#2 /var/www/html/drupal/modules/php/php.module(81): drupal_eval('<?php?$curl = c...')\n#3 [internal function]: php_filter('process', '0', '5', '<?php?$curl = c...', '5:cc75e663c59c9...')\n#4 /var/www/html/drupal/includes/module.inc(476): call_user_func_array('php_filter', Array)\n#5 /var/www/html/drupal/modules/filter/filter.module(455): module_invoke('php', 'filter', 'process', '0', '5', '<?php?$curl = c...', '5:cc75e663c59c9...')\n#6 /var/www/html/drupal/modules/node/node.module(1054): check_markup('<?php??$curl = ...', '5', false)\n#7 /var/www/html/drupal/modules/node/node.module(1098): node_prepare(Object(stdClass), false)\n#8 /var/www/html/drupal/modules/node/node.module(1019): node_build_cont in /var/www/html/drupal/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 6,`

I've no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can you elaborate for which parts of the message *"String could not be parsed as XML"* specifically you have no idea about? How is that error message a puzzle to you? What did you expect instead? Can you perhaps say why? - Unless you don't share more context, the code you've posted looks correct and the error message makes totally sense.

Answer (score 0):

So the error is basically saying that you're getting a string but you're trying to treat is as XML.

Look at your source - http://www.pinterest.com/myaccount/rss.
Can your web server access the XML that is supposedly there? Because I sure can't. If I go there, I get redirected to some other page. And surely if I made a cURL command there, I am going to get that page... as a string, because that is what it is, not XML.

I presume that this is indeed XML content but you likely need to be logged in to view it - and there is your problem - your web server does not have a valid login to Pinterest and therefore cannot see the XML. You may wish to investigate whether it is possible for your to use cURL to authenticate and then access that XML.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, the URL you've provided in your question does not contain any XML:

```
http://www.pinterest.com/myaccount/rss
```

However, there is an URL you most likely meant to use instead, which does contain XML:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/myaccount/feed.rss
```

Please take note that this is independent to Drupal. It's just that you didn't provide valid XML to the constructor of [**SimpleXMLElement**](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement).

Comment: Oh... What I fool I am sometimes.
It's ok with the correct URL, many thanks